# Getentity method in vb.net + Autocad?

Tags: vb.net, autocad, vb6-migration

```
ACADAPP = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")

ACADDOC = ACADAPP.Documents.ActiveDocument
second_POINT = ACADDOC.Utility.GetEntity(select_object, , "Select Object <Enter to Exit> : ")
```

`ACADDOC.Utility.GetEntity` returns an error as

> type mismatch

in vb.net autocad,when I'm trying with vb6 it works fine.

Comment: I think, if you tell us this, it is so. What do you expect now?

Comment: I just want to fetch block details from autocad from vb.net

Comment: What data type is `select_object`?  If there's a data type mismatch then data types are probably something to look at.

Comment: select_object is just an object which is don't have a value, later that statement onlyit can be bind value to it

Answer (score 0):

What about that 2nd empty parameter - is that correct? According to the specification, it expects an object - a point.

```
object.GetEntity Object, PickedPoint [, Prompt]
```

Such as...

```
ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity returnObj, basePnt, "Prompt, i.e. Select an object"
```

By the way - is that really a VB.NET? Or Visual Basic for Application (VBA)? Notice, there are significant differences in syntax and capabilities... The AutoDesk general documentation (incl. online) would be for VBA, not VB.NET.

EDIT:

```
Dim returnObj As AcadObject
Dim basePnt As Variant

ThisDrawing.Utility.GetEntity returnObj, basePnt, "Select an object"
```

Note, that this example is for VBA, I've never worked with VB.NET and ACAD, I'm not even sure how it is supported.
Make sure you handle **empty selection** too...

Comment: No, I have tried this too, Vb.net gives an exception as type mismatched. Thanks for your reply. Please give me some other answer for this one

Comment: OK, if you didn't try, for this error I'd then define two variables Dim RetObj as new Object and BasePoint as New Point ans set the info there. Put those into your command instead. You'll probably find out, that the error will appear isolated on one of the lines, where you'll be assigning variables. Then try i.e. RetObj = CAST(inputObj, Object). See what you'll get and let us know...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that will return a selected object.

The PromptEntityResult's ObjectId Property is the actual returned entity, which you will have to get to with a transaction.

```
Public Shared Function GetEntity() As PromptEntityResult
    Dim retVal As PromptEntityResult = Nothing
    Dim oDoc As Document = Core.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
    Dim oEd As Editor = oDoc.Editor
    Dim oPeo As New PromptEntityOptions(Environment.NewLine & "Please select an object")

    With oPeo
        .SetRejectMessage(Environment.NewLine & "Cannot select that object.")
        .AllowNone = False
        .AllowObjectOnLockedLayer = True
    End With

    retVal = oEd.GetEntity(oPeo)

    Return retVal
End Function
```